# How to resolve jenkins npm install Permission denied

Tags: docker, jenkins, npm

This is my Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  tools {nodejs "nodejs10"}
  stages {
      stage('Test') {
        steps {
          echo 'Testing...'
        }
      }
      stage ('Build source') {
        steps {
          sh '''
            mkdir -p .npm-global
            mkdir -p _cacache
            export PATH=.npm-global/bin:$PATH

            npm config set prefix '.npm-global'
            npm config set cache '_cacache'
            npm config set jobs 1
            npm config set strict-ssl false
          '''
          dir('e2e/test1'){
            sh "$PWD"
          }
          sh 'npm i'
        }
      }
  }
}
```

It fails at the npm install.
I get this error:

```
Pipeline] dir
Running in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/jenkins_docker2/e2e/test1
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ /
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/jenkins_docker2/e2e/test1@tmp/durable-e0a8070a/script.sh: 1: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/jenkins_docker2/e2e/test1@tmp/durable-e0a8070a/script.sh: /: Permission denied
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
```

Am I missing something in my pipeline?

I have nodejs plugin with node10.
I have build the jenkins using docker on my windows 10 operating system using docker community edition using a volume as such:

```
docker run -p 81:8080 -p 50000:50000 --name myjenkins --privileged -v %cd%/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have discovered npm install works when I don't use dir and I place my package.json file in the root. IT doesn't explain why I get permission denied by changing the working directory to a different folder that has package.json, but for now I have a working solution.

Comment: I don't think the issue from `dir`, but `sh "$PWD"`,  Can you try change it to `sh 'pwd'`